# How does constant reference makes a difference?

Tags: c++

I dont understand why the following code doesn't work:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class PayOff{};
class PayOffCall : public PayOff{};

class PayOffBridge{
public:
    PayOffBridge( PayOff& innerPayOff){};
};

class VanilaOption{
public:
   VanilaOption(PayOffBridge& ThePayOff_){cout << " test " <<endl;}
};


int main () {
PayOffCall thePayOff;
VanilaOption theOption(thePayOff);
  return 0;
}
```

For some reason changing the reference to const in VanilaOption class (code below) makes it work, can someone explain how does it work? The error I get is: *no matching function for call to 'VanilaOption::VanilaOption(PayOffCall&)'*

but it doesn't help me to figure it out.

```
class VanilaOption{
public:
   VanilaOption(const PayOffBridge& ThePayOff_){cout << " test " <<endl;}
};
```

I also don't understand why passing PayOffCall reference when PayOffBridge reference is expected works, can someone help me out on this?

Thank you!

Comment: Could you rewrite the question with short names like `Foo`, `Bar` and `Qux` rather than ReallLongNamesThatOnlyDifferInTheLastFewLetters? It might make the mistake in thinking easier to spot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original code doesn't work because `thePayOff` isn't a value of type `PayOffBridge`, but rather of type `PayOffCall`.

The modified code works because it allows the construction of a temporary `PayOffBridge` object from the `PayOff` subobject of the `PayOffCall` object, and then construct the `VanillaOption` object from that temporary. That is because:

1. the `PayOffBridge` constructor is non-explicit,
2. an lvalue of a derived class can be converted to an lvalue of any of its accessible base classes, and
3. because temporaries can bind to const lvalue references (but not to non-const lvalue references).

In other words, the const reference version allows code like:

```
VanilaOption theOption(PayOffBridge(thePayOff));
//                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-----< temporary
```

Whereas for the non-const version you'd need a mutable lvalue, perhaps like:

```
PayOffBridge b(thePayOff);
VanilaOption theOption(b);
//                     ^----- lvalue
```

Answer (score 1):

A `PayoffCall` (like `thePayoff` variable) is not a `PayOffBridge`, so it can't be bound to a reference to `PayOffBridge`.

However, it can be *converted* to `PayOffBridge`, via the converting `PayOffBridge` constructor.

With a reference to `const` argument such a conversion is performed, producing a temporary that's bound to the formal argument.

A reference to `const` can in general be bound to a temporary.

An ordinary reference to non-`const` can't be bound to a temporary.